# accessing image_tag helper from console nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm trying to access image_tag helper from console.

(in ruby 1.9.2, **rails 3.0.1**)

I tryed out solutions

```
helper.image_tag("rails.png")
```

even

```
foo = ActionView::Base.new
foo.image_tag "rails.png"
```

I always get the same error

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
from /home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lovethis/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:790:in `join'
from /home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lovethis/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:790:in `rails_asset_id'
from /home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lovethis/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:813:in `rewrite_asset_path'
from /home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lovethis/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:742:in `compute_public_path'
from /home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lovethis/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:561:in `image_path'
from /home/tomi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@lovethis/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:631:in `image_tag'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a real answer for you but based on what I've found it doesn't seem to be possible.  The nil error is coming from this line because `config.assets_dir` is nil:

```
path = File.join(config.assets_dir, source)
```

It's nil because config = `{}`.  And I believe it's empty because in line 220 in actionpack-3.0.7/action_view/base.rb `controller` is nil:

```
config = controller && controller.respond_to?(:config) ? controller.config : {}
```

I know that doesn't help much but if someone can figure out how to override that at console start maybe it'll work.

As an aside, why do you want to do that in the console anyway?  Seems it'd be just as easy to put it into a view and hit reload.

Comment: Thx for response, I tried out to play with console once more, and when I do `controller.config.assets_dir`  I get path  "/media/work_volume/project/project/public" but you are right that `controller.config` is  {}... do you have any other thounghts ?  ...anyway I'm rendering a view each time so I don't need console, but I found It much faster to do these things from console and in future I will need it ...thx